# my CPU speed is at 100% plus my speed is beyond its limits and showing wrong (I think)

Tags: windows, cpu

Basically, both Task Manager and Resource Monitor show my CPU at 100% with my speed on TM at around 30000000,00GHz (though I'm not sure if that's just how it displays).

Now, my CPU can do 2.80 GHz yet goes above that into the 3+ GHz area - now on Process Explorer it's on around 10%-ish every so often jumping to 90% for a few seconds (when doing something).

I used AVG and it found nothing: no problems, no viruses, nothing, can't seem to find an answer so please I need a little help.

[image]

Comment: Each CPU (you have more than one) represents 0-100% usage.  3 of your CPUs maxed out would show as 300%.  Doesn't explain the 30000000,00GHz though.

Comment: What model is the CPU? My guess is you have a CPU with a base sped below 3ghz but will burst faster. Alternatively you might be over clocking it (which can sometimes be done in BIOS)

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas uhm, unless you are on a server environment where you have actual CPU's, thats not true. If you have one CPU with multiple cores (that is a mistake often made) then all cores total up to 100% but if one core is used fully, and the rest not, its a percentage of 100. For example a 4 core CPU would max one core out as 25% CPU usage.

Comment: @davidgo my first go would be that it shows as hz, not ghz. But yeah, it probably has a turbo feature.

Comment: @lpchip re the 300% - I'm confident you will find SenorXMasMas correct - at least that is the case in Linux systems. Each core is 100%, so it is possible to get 400% on Linux on a single CPU machine.

Comment: @davidg , you are correct, I was thinking of linux (meaning not thinking).. &-P  and LPChip is probably also correct..

Answer (score 1):

If we look at the specifications for the [Intel® Core™ i5-2300 Processor](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/52206/intel-core-i5-2300-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-10-ghz.html), we can see they say:

> Processor Base Frequency 2.80 GHz

which is the maximum speed it will run at *usually*.

The next line tells us:

> Max Turbo Frequency 3.10 GHz

with some help text starting with:

> Max turbo frequency is the maximum single core frequency at which the processor is capable of operating using Intel® Turbo Boost Technology

The idea of Turbo Boost is to get the job over and done with as quickly as possible, which can lead to some energy saving compared to the normal maximum frequency. Intel have an [article which goes into more detail](https://www.intel.co.uk/content/www/uk/en/architecture-and-technology/turbo-boost/turbo-boost-technology.html).

So, the processor in your computer is expected to run a little past the frequency in its name when there is an increased processing load.

---

As for the somewhat optimistic 30000000,00GHz, it may be displaying that as a result of the regional settings in Windows.